# How to turn off/on Google activity permissions by individual apps

Tags: applications, google

Does anyone know how to turn off/on Google activity tracking by individual apps? There's no option in the Google activity settings.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: My google activity stopped showing when I just apps now. I really need to know how to turn it on to show when I use Google meet. Really everything that it's not showing but particularly that one. It's ruining my relationship cause they think ive turned it off on purpose. I've searched Google help articles for hours and still haven't had any luck. I've combed my settings in my phone and haven't had any luck. I have a s23 ultra

Answer (score 1):

There is no such setting for apps.  Google activity tracking is on the Google account.

All I can see on mine is

- Web & App Activity
- Location History
- YouTube History